# Disable weekends and previous dates - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using the below code to insert a date picker text box.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script>    
function MainController($scope) {    
$scope.date = new Date();    
}    
</script>    


<body ng-app>    
<div ng-controller="MainController">    
<input type="date" ng-model="date" value="{{ date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}" />    
</body>
```

**Angular JS Calendar**

[image]

I would like to if the below is possible to implement;

A. disable weekends selection

B. disable previous dates (starting yesterday)

C. disable 4 days including today (ex. if today is 12 then from 12 to 17 should be disabled - which includes weekends as well that are already disabled)

I have done this using JQuery Datepicker but not able to do it with AngularJS. Please help.

**Attached screenshot of Jquery Datepicker.**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to achieve A, B and C as mentioned? Please advise.

Comment: Thank you @georgeawg. I wanted to know if the above (A,B and C) are possible to achieve using the AngularJS method I am using because I could achieve the same using JQuery pickup calendar. I wanted to know if it is the right approach or do I need to do take a difference approach. Hope I am able to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are relying on browsers' implementation of `<input>`, which is not very powerful. Using this, you can't grey out specific dates, only ranges using `min` and `max` attributes (which makes your B objective achievable).

There are several solutions from the AJS community, including:

- [`ui-date`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date), apparently a copy-paste of jQuery's picker you're used to (read the warnings though, they don't sell it as the best solution)
- [UI Bootstrap's datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) seems more powerful and is referred to by `ui-date`'s page - yet I don't see how you'd achieve A and C objectives using its options
- the proven [`md-datepicker`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker), which allows you to achieve B with `md-min-date` and `md-max-date`, and to achieve A, B and C with `md-date-filter`; demos are [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) (my personal favorite, in case it's not obvious enough ^^)

Comment: Can you please check why the date picker is not showing up? http://jsfiddle.net/amogzcvu/

Comment: I never use this Resources linker, seems it's involved in the issue. [This forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fot85Lu2/2/) works though. I only moved your JS to the HTML area, and removed the dual AJS loading  (1 in Resources, 1 as the JS panel setting).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and all the help. It was really helpful.

Comment: Cheers mate! :)

Comment: Just facing an issue. I am bit stuck as it doesn't work inside asp.net page and AngularJS already built into it. Do I need to do something?

Comment: No idea, but you shouldn't have to do anything more. Maybe it's the same kind of issue you had in JSFiddle (loading order of scripts or the like)...

Comment: I am adding links to the 10 resources on the top like <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.10/angular-material.css"></script> and so on.

Comment: The Loading order of scripts is exactly like it is in the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k9qg6azp/

Comment: No idea from here, I'd say check the console and the source